# IHP - Unable to retrieve special characters from request body

Tags: haskell, ihp

I'm trying to send the request using ajax:

```js
    const formBody = document.getElementById('body'); // my form data
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const params = "body=" + formBody;
    
    XHR.open("POST", window.origin + '/CreateFormAction');
    XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    XHR.send(params);
```

The corresponding IHP action:

```hs
action CreatePostAction = do
        rBody <- getRequestBody
        putStrLn $ tshow rBody -- this returns: ""
        renderPlain "Request Received"
```

When I try sending special characters like '$', '+', etc., this is the request I get on server:

```
POST /CreatePostMessage
  Params: [("body"," ")]
  Request Body: body=+
  Accept: */*
  Status: 200 OK 0.025023s
```

Comment: I'm surprised you end up with `body=+`. I would have expected something like `body=[object HTMLFormElement]` since you're converting an object representing an HTML element into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the formBody using `encodeURIComponent()` to encode special characters as follows:

```
const params = "body=" + encodeURIComponent(formBody);
```

Your IHP action should be able to handle special characters then.